# Playing background music in a React app using Howler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, react-state-management, howler.js

So im using Howler to play background music when my React app is loaded. So I store ID of the instance of Howler(i.e is responsible for background music) using useState hook. I have a button in the app to toggle pause and play in the app. The problem is, when ever my site rerenders, a new instance is started playing and when I pause nothing pauses.

```
  const [aid, setAid] = useState(null);
  const [sp, setSp] = useState(false);

function handleBgSound() {
    if (sp) {
      amb.pause(aid);
      setSp(false)
    }
     else if (!sp) {
      setAid(amb.play())
      setSp(true)
    } else {
      amb.pause();
    }
  }
```

Im frustrated with this and would appreciate any help or leads!!

Comment: In which component are you declaring these states? Also, when you say "when ever my site rerenders", are we talking about React navigation or refreshing the browser window?

Comment: Hi @ChrisG , I'm declaring these states along with many others in this same component itself. And "when ever my site rerenders" what I mean by this is, Im using useEffect hook too within this same component to update certain things on the UI, so whenever their happens any update, a new instance of this Howl is started and I can literally hear it start playing...

Comment: If you can even give me any resource for using Howler for background music in React app, that too would be awesome @ChrisG !!